# How to fire intent if i have only target activity object

Tags: android

I have an object of activity i.e. my target activity and i want to fire intent to that activity.I tried with application context but it is not working.

```
             Activity act=primaryActivityContextList.peek();
            Intent intent =new Intent(act.getApplicationContext,act.getClass());
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PRIMARY_DISPLAY);
                primaryActivityContextList.peek().startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about how is it "not working" ?

Comment: it is not firing any intent as target activity is SingleTask and when i tried to debug it onnewIntent method is not receiving call

Answer (score 2):

I'm new in Android, I'm not very sure but try this.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(PrimaryActivity.this, PrimaryActivity.class); 
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: in this code primaryactivity is the target activity or source activity